# MASM lengthof array

Tags: arrays, assembly, masm

I have a rather large array that I need to do some processing with, and when I try to store its LENGTHOF in a register, it only stores the lengthof of the first line of the array, not the whole array. The array must be declared exactly like this, as it comes directly from a homework assignment. any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

the array declaration:

```
ages DWORD 4, 7, 4, 4, 8, 5, 4, 8, 4, 6, 6, 7, 4
DWORD 7, 5, 3, 4, 4, 6, 5, 4, 6, 5, 8, 7, 4, 5, 7
DWORD 6, 5, 7, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 5, 7, 5, 3, 5, 3, 6
DWORD 9, 6, 4, 7, 5, 4, 9
```

when I write:

```
mov ecx, LENGTHOF ages
```

the value stored in ecx is only 13.

Comment: Not sure about MSAM but create a label at the end for data and calculate `ages_end-ages` to get the length.

Comment: @Simson: They want the length in elements, not bytes, so `ages_len = ($ - ages) / 4`.  But yeah, that's the standard way to get the assembler to calculate sizes of static data for you, although MASM's `LENGTHOF` is apparently a handy shortcut if it's convenient to declare a whole array on one line.